# get and post request to a https site using vb6.0

Tags: vb6, serverxmlhttp

Hi i am using MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP40 to get and post request to a url.When i post to http site it works fine but when i post to https site it throws me an error stating the operation timed out.I am not able to get the response.Kindly help me out.Thanks in advance

Comment: Is your HTTP/HTTPS access from your location proxied?  ServerXMLHTTP doesn't use WinInet, it uses the WinHTTP stack which means it isn't using your IE proxy settings unless you set them.

Comment: yeah i tried using  the following code myHttpRequest.setProxy SXH_PROXY_SET_PROXY, "http://172.16.4.242:8080"... but still i get the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Found the solution I have to set the ..setproxy and setproxycredentials along and also i need to get the session id .When i used all the three it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

By default HTTP will use port 80 but HTTPS uses port 443. Is it possible that you've got a firewall blocking port 443?
I'd suggest trying to connect to both sites from a webbrowser to make sure it all works.

Comment: Thanks but i tried already tat is working in webbrowser.It's nt blocked